# Timeout while waiting for sandboxed code execution request to complete within the worker process

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

I'm using Sharepoint 2010 Online (BPOS) site.

I have deployed a Visual sandbox solution in the list Edit form. The List have contain around 4000 rows.

Now while users tries to edit the List item, I'm encountering a time out error. But edit form opens while users attempt for some more time.

What is the cause and solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its the disadvantage of using SharePoint online.

Basically it supports light weighted solution. If you wsp consumes more than 30 seconds for processing any data, then your solution fails.

Just decide before you designing the solution in share point online, does your requirement requires more than 30 sec to process.

Hope it will help..